# What was the episode from British/American Anthology about husband buying a clone?

Tags: story-identification, clones

There was an episode of a Sci-fi/horror anthology. Either a TV series, or a series of movies. It was about a man whose wife is starved for affection, and overly attentive, trying to win his love. He buys a clone/robot to replace him so he can have some free time. On down time, the clone is kept in cold storage in the basement. The clone ends up being super romantic and treating the wife better than the husband did. They fight for her at the end of the episode.

Where is this story from?

Comment: It sounds vaguely similar to *Multiplicity* - however, since I only know the plot of that movie from the Simpsons' parody of it on one of their Halloween episodes, I can't really say for certain.

Comment: @RDFozz - I'm baffled why you'd link that question to this one...

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! You may want to take the [tour], for more insight on how the site works. This is a good start, but you may want to see the answers to [this question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/) for additional information you may be able to provide. For example: Do you know when you saw/heard of this story? That can narrow down the possibilities. What about how long this specific story was (as you think it was part of an anthology, implying multiple stories if it was a movie).

Comment: Hey, @Valorum, watch me pull a rabbit out of this hat! *Roar* Wrong hat! (Sadly, the worst of it is this is the *second* question that I cut and pasted that wrong question link into. Sigh.)

Comment: @RDFozz - [I pity the fool who doesn't listen to Mr. T](https://memegenerator.net/img/instances/73424088/dont-drink-and-post.jpg)

Comment: Thanks. I searched every tag I could think of looking for the episodes. Gave up and posted a question. Yes. @Valorum It was Marionettes, Inc.. Thank you so much everyone for your help.